# The radio starts. But it doesn't stop. It doesn't stop when I switch pages in the project

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-streaming, setstate, bottombar

I want the radio to stop when switching between pages. It works the first time I press the stop and start button, but when I press it again when I want to stop it does not stop. The radio is always on and never turns off. When I close the app completely, the radio stops. I want to do both stop and resume operation on the same button, and I want it to stop when I switch between pages. how can i solve?

code here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_radio/flutter_radio.dart';
class RadioSayfasi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioSayfasiState createState() => _RadioSayfasiState();
}

class _RadioSayfasiState extends State<RadioSayfasi> {
  String url= "https://player.web.tr/listen/d695bfdfb2710f7c53feb05550da66ef";

  bool isPlaying= false;
  bool isVisible= true;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    audioStart();
  }

  Future <void> audioStart() async {
    await FlutterRadio.audioStart();
    print("Radio Başladı");
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'IndieXL Online Radio',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: const Text('FM Radio'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: Container(
            color: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 7,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.radio, size: 250,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                      child: IconButton(icon: isPlaying? Icon(
                        Icons.pause_circle_outline,
                        size: 80,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )
                          : Icon(
                        Icons.play_circle_outline,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 80,
                      ),
                        onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            FlutterRadio.play(url: url);
                            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                            isVisible = !isVisible;
                            print("tıkladı");
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50,)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that would cause audio to stop playing, only to start playing. Read the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_radio) of the package you are using to know how to stop its playback.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the package you are using was discontinued over a year ago. You might want to look into a newer actively maintained package, especially if you intend to use Flutter 2.0+ with null safety at some point.

Comment: why null safety

Comment: Flutter 2.0 uses Dart 2.12, so it will have the new null safety feature of that version of Dart. This puts its backward compatibility to prior versions of Flutter (and packages designed for such) complicated, to say the least. The short version is this: if your project depends on pre-null-safety Flutter, your project will never be able to fully upgrade to the newest versions of Flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the library you mention, https://github.com/thyagoluciano/flutter_radio

To stop radio stream when leaving the screen just override the dispose method

https://github.com/thyagoluciano/flutter_radio/blob/master/lib/flutter_radio.dart#L67

```
@action
dispose() async {
    await FlutterRadio.stop();
}
```

To start or pause radio stream
https://github.com/thyagoluciano/flutter_radio/blob/master/lib/flutter_radio.dart#L22

```
onPressed: (){ 
    setState(() { 
        //FlutterRadio.play(url: url); 
        FlutterRadio.playOrPause(url: url); 
        isPlaying = !isPlaying; 
        isVisible = !isVisible; 
        print("tıkladı"); 
    }); 
},
```

Comment: I start the radio automatically. I made it play again when switching between pages. but when it comes to the radio page again, a new radio is playing even though the radio is on. 2 radios are playing at the same time. If the radio is on, I don't want it to play the new radio when I come back to the radio page. I searched a lot but couldn't find it.